# can't choose ".value" option for input value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I really cant understand why it's not working, here is my html:

```
<form>
    <h1 class="forms_container_title">Registration form: </h1>
    <div class="form_items">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>
    <div class="form_items">
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Enter your surname">
    </div>
    <div class="form_items">
        <input type="email" name="emal" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
    <div class="form_items">
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
</form>

<div id="submit_form">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

and this is simple javascprit, for example:

```
const fname = document.getElementById("name");
```

and I want to get its value with ".value", but it's only showing ".nodevalue" option, whyy ???

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other, non-input, elements with id `name` in your document? That would be invalid HTML, and would cause this problem. (I'm not saying that's definitely the problem, but it's the most obvious thing I can think of right now.)

Comment: And if that's not the issue, can you please share the exact Javascript you're using to access the value - maybe there is a syntax issue with that which we can't tell from your description.

Comment: no i am sure that id name is only one and exact javascprit is this :  `const name = document.getElementById("name")`

Comment: and when i am writing `.value` its only shows `.nodeValue`

Comment: `and when i am writing .value its only shows .nodeValue`, do you mean in your IDE?

Comment: yes, I mean that